# How to update the first row with its second row values in case some columns are duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

So lets assume i have a table products where i have the below data

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| ProductID | ProductName | Value |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
|         1 | Box         | NULL  |
|         2 | PEN         | 10    |
|         3 | BOX         | 10    |
|         4 | KITE        | 20    |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

Now i want to update the table like below

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| ProductID | ProductName | Value |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
|         1 | Box         | 10    |
|         2 | PEN         | 10    |
|         3 | BOX         | 10    |
|         4 | KITE        | 20    |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

as you could see i need to find all the productname which are having null and update them with values from the product having the same name.

> Assuming that we may have multiple "box" with null and all "Box" will have same value and lot of data.

Comment: What if same `product` have different `value` ? which one do you want to update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self joins may not scale well with many rows containing the same product. This is a simple way of avoiding self joins. This only updates columns that contains null when there is a matching column with actual data.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    [Value],
    max([Value])over(partition by Productname)NewValue
  FROM [YourTable]
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET [Value] = NewValue
WHERE [Value] is null and NewValue is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sub-query:

```
update p 
    set p.value = (select max(p1.value) 
                   from Product p1 
                   where p1.productname = p.productname and p1.value is not null
                  )
from Product p
where p.value is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a self-join here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p2.Value AS ValueSource, p1.Value AS ValueTarget
    FROM products p1
    INNER JOIN products p2
        ON p1.ProductName = p2.ProductName AND
           p2.Value IS NOT NULL AND p1.Value IS NULL
)

UPDATE cte
SET ValueTarget = ValueSource;
```

The idea here is to pair up records having the same product name, but different product ID values.  Then, we update the "duplicate" having the `NULL` value with the non `NULL` value.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk It wasn't initially clear that `NULL` was the criteria here.

Answer (score 0):

First find all the records which are having same productname.
then apply a row number and save it in CTE
later join this table with main table and use a case condition for checking null and update it.
the where claue will reduce the number of records returned from CTE (as we dont need null value)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductName  ORDER BY ProductName ) AS rno,
      ProductID,Value,ProductName 
  from Product where ProductName in
(SELECT ProductName FROM Product Group By(ProductName) having count(ProductName)>1)
)


Update FR SET FR.Value = CASE WHEN FR.Value IS NULL THEN CTE.Value ELSE FR.Value END
from Product FR
inner join CTE CTE on CTE.ProductName = FR.ProductName
where CTE.Value is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0d78a8b09f4cda39763eeafa60b450a)

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` combines with `CTE` to achieve it.

```
;with cte as (
 select ProductName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName ORDER BY [Value]) rn,Value 
 from #a
)
update #a
set #a.Value = cte.Value
from #a
inner join cte on cte.ProductName = #a.ProductName
where rn <> 1--#a.Value is null and cte.Value is not null
```

Comment: @Tejaswi Pandava Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help